# Implementing twitter login in Symfony 1.4 without sfGuard

Tags: twitter, symfony1, symfony-1.4, twitter-oauth

I've an existing project in symfony 1.4. **Worse thing, project is not using sfGuard plugin but implemented custom user authentication.**

As a new feature requirement, client requested to add `login with twitter` support in the app.

I went through [twitter PHP libs](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries#php) which seems do not fit for symfony 1.4 without some level of customization.

I also went with one Symfony plugin (sorry but forget the link) but it also do not meet my requirements as (I guess) it is tightly coupled with sfGuard.

I started customizing [tmhOAuth](https://github.com/themattharris/tmhOAuth) to match my requirements but I'd like to ask; **is there is any symfony 1.4 plugin for twitter, which do not depends on sfGuard?**

Comment: Without sfGuard, I don't know one. You should use tmhOAuth.

Comment: Thanks J0k, after some more searching, I too guess customization is only option as requirements are rare & on old framework too. Customizing tmhOAuth a bit right now to fit in symfony 1.4.